# C-c C-r for Ocaml toplevel and setting a region under Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, ocaml

I have seen somewhere the description of `C-c C-r` is "evaluate the whole selected region" or `tuareg-eval-region`. But when I try it under `Emacs`, it seems that after setting a region, and placing the cursor several commands after the end of the region, pressing `C-c C-r` evaluates until the position of the cursor.

So could anyone tell me if `C-c C-r` evaluates "until the cursor" or a region that we set before?

By the way, I am not sure I have set the region correctly. One way is to use `SHIFT + direction arrow`; another way is to use `CTRL + space`, but i do not know the difference between `Mark set`, `Mark activated` and `Mark cleared`. Could anyone tell me the right way to select a region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Emacs parlance, the *region* is the area between the *mark* and *point* (i.e., the cursor).  Thus, when you move the cursor, you move one boundary of the region while the other remains wherever the current mark is.

`C-SPC` is the traditional way of setting the mark.  Nowadays, Shift + cursor keys should work as well.  See the [relevant section of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html#Mark) for details on how regions work.